# Genymotion doesnt show mistakes

Tags: android, genymotion

I'm having hard time to find answer in Google to this stupid question. 
I come from C# to android development and in C# when my application crush, the compiler shows where exactly my application crush in the code and I can see the values of all the variables.

For now, my app crush and I got no idea where to search the mistake.

Is this possible to have in android Eclipse with GenyMotion emulator this behavior? How?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Eclipse and Android, but after having that installed and running an app, a log viewer should popup where you can filter and search for specific things. Maybe this is of interest for you: https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq/#get-logcat

Comment: Please don't swear in your comments.  This is not Facebook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a logging facility on Android called LogCat. You can open it in Eclipse by going to menu Window > Show View > Other... > LogCat.

Any uncaught exceptions will be printed in red color. The filter for your application will be created when you run it.

[image: LogCat example]

Comment: This is my log - not relevant. What you need to do is run your application, select the package name in the Saved filters window and when the app crashes the stack will appear in red font. There will be line numbers so you know where to look.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this pissibol to have in android Eclipce with genymotion emulator this behavior? How?

To fix your crash first look at the exception in the logcat then try to understand what exactly that error message. For example : `NullPointerException` then probably you are trying to access which you haven't initialized.

Now to see variable then use debug feature of the IDE. In eclipse with Genymotion or device you can debug your application then use Ctrl + F6 to trace line by line.